# Profiling JUnit tests with PowerMock?

Tags: jsf, junit, profiling, powermock

We have a couple of very very slow JUnit tests that make heavy use of mocking, including Mocking of static functions. Single Tests take 20-30 secs, the whole "mvn test" takes 25 minutes.

I want to analyze where the time is wasted but have little experience in profiling.

I assume that the initialization of the dependent mock-objects takes much too long.

Two questions:

1) How can I quickly get numbers in which methods the time is wasted? I need no complex power-user tool, just something basic to get the numbers. (evidence that the kind of mocking we do is evil)

2) Do you have ideas what design-flaws can produce such bad timings? We test JSF-backing beans that should call mocked services. Perhaps there might be some input-validation or not-refactored business logic in the backing beans, but that cannot be changed (pls dont comment on that ;-) )

ad 2) For example one test has about 30 (!) classes to be prepared for test with @PrepareForTest. This cannot be good, but I cannot explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my input on this:

1. Try using something simple like the [Apache Commons StopWatch class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html).  I find that this is an easy way to spot bottle necks in code, and usually when you find what the first bottlneck is then the rest of them are easier to spot.  I almost never waste my time trying to configure an overly complicated profiling tool.
2. I think it is odd that you have such performance flaws in fully mocked unit tests.  If I were to guess I would say that you are missing one or two mocked components and the database or external web services are actually being called without you knowing about it.  Of course I may be wrong, because I don't use PowerMock and I make it a point to never mock **any** static methods.  That is your biggest design flaw right now and the biggest hindrance to providing good test coverage on your code.  So what to do?  You have 2 options, you can refactor the static methods into class methods that can be more easily mocked.  The other option is that you wrap the static methods in a class object wrapper, and then mock the wrapper instead.  I typically do this if the static methods are from a third-party library where I do not have the source.
3. `one test has about 30 (!) classes to be prepared for test with @PrepareForTest. This cannot be good, but I cannot explain why.` This really sounds like you may also have methods that are *doing entirely too much!*  That is just too many dependencies for a single method in about 99% of cases.  More than likely this method can be seperated into seperate more easily testable methods.

Hope this helps.